# Hacking Terminal Messages

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, open-source, signals

This is weird question but I want to know how to change message coming on terminal For Eg-

```
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~$ cat seg.c 
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int* p=9;
    printf("%x",*p);
}
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault
```

I want to change message "Segmentation fault" to something else .. like "Pointer failure".

There is no specific purpose behind this, I just want to explore power of open source.

I try to grep in Linux Kernel source code -

```
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~$ cd linux-3.0.1/
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~/linux-3.0.1$ grep -r "Segmentation fault" *
Documentation/s390/Debugging390.txt:Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
Documentation/virtual/uml/UserModeLinux-HOWTO.txt:  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~/linux-3.0.1$
```

As the massage come, it should be somewhere in my system.

I think, I am searching at wrong place.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The message is printed by your shell.

Comment: A segmentation fault is not always a pointer failure. For instance, in x86, the `hlt` instruction causes a segmentation fault (it causes a GPF which Linux translates to a segmentation fault) when used from user space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mat commented, the message is coming from your shell.

Since your shell is probably free software (probably [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), but you could also use some others, I like [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/)) you might take time to patch it accordingly.

But I believe you should not do that, because otherwise you won't be able to explain what your system happens to do. For instance, if your modified shell outputs "`Pointer failure`", nobody would understand a question here which mentions that.

It seems much simpler to learn the usual things in Linux...

Comment: I grep and replace all "Segmentation fault" messages in /bash-4.1 source code compiled and installed .... but doesn't work.
When i grep again i found message "Segmentation fault" in some binary files like `Binary file po/es.gmo matches
po/ro.po:msgstr "Eroare de segmentare (Segmentation fault)"`
... now how can I replace message in binary files ??

Comment: It is related to internationalization features.